# autoit unable to access treeview control

Tags: .net, treeview, autoit

I have a window with what looks to be a treeview control, but I am unable to gather any information from it, or control it.  The information is as follows

WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.13f082a_r27_ad151
[NAME:utFolders]

I am hoping to find a way to loop through the items, checking each final child item one at a time and take some action.  From what I have gathered this is a .NET control, but I have not been able to find information on accessing/processing it.  Is it possible to control this item?

collapsed view:

[image]

expanded view:

[image]

Comment: Try using this instead: https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/

Comment: I will check there, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Richard's comment led to the solution, Thank you
https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153520-iuiautomation-ms-framework-automate-chrome-ff-ie/